# UINavigationItem's click area reduced in ios 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

[image]

In ios 10 the clickable area on UINavigationBar was pretty much the area of the rectangle but in ios 11 it takes only the size of the image. Below is the code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedSpace setWidth:-5];

UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"];

UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[closeButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width,   buttonImage.size.height);

UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:closeButton];

[closeButton addTarget:navTarget action:@selector(didSelectCloseButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[navItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixedSpace,aBarButtonItem,nil]];
```

I am sure there might be something wrong with the code but in Xcode 8 and ios 10 its working fine but not in ios 11. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is expected behaviour in iOS 11, now in iOS 11 UINavigationbar  supports auto-layout and the title's width is increased therefore size of UIBarButtonItem is decreased. nothing is wrong with any other apis but to mimic previous version behaviour there are some workarounds.

Comment: Can you please point out some workarounds?

Comment: Well, the workaround is the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47221408/3308174) by Kiran Sarvaiya

Comment: Yeah apart from that. anyways thanks.